# Testing debounced method in React with Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, lodash, jestjs, enzyme

```
//Component
import _ from 'lodash';

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.onScroll = _.debounce(::this.onScroll, 100);
}

onScroll() {
  //some code
}

//Test
it('onScroll', () => {
  const component = shallow(<Component />);
  component.instance().onScroll(); //Dosn't call method 
})
```

I use enzyme for render component, and lodash for `debounce`. How to call `component.instance().onScroll()`?

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR; use [`lolex`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lolex) to advance in time [while mocking timers](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2234#issuecomment-332831046) for testing `_.debounce`

I was ready to describe several ways to mock timers with jest by `useFakeTimers` and `advanceTimersByTime`. But it did not work.

After some time I've found it works with `_.throttle` but not `_.debounce`.
And then I've found [issue reported](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3465) in Jest's repo. Also there is dedicated bug report ["_.debounce breaks fake timers"](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/2893) and I don't see it's resolved(ignore its status and check last comments there).

According to veeeeery [detailed explanation](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3465#issuecomment-424193697) `_.debounce` not just put `setTimeout` but also checks time difference. So we should mock also `Date.now` that Jest's `jest.runOnlyPendingTimers` or `jest.advanceTimersByTime` don't do.

So for simple component like

```
function Debounced({onClick}) {
    return <button onClick={_debounce(onClick,500)}>Click Me</button>;  
}
```

next test has passed:

```
let clock = lolex.install();
const onClick = jest.fn();
const wrapper = shallow(<Debounced onClick={onClick} />);
const button = wrapper.find('button').at(0);

button.simulate('click');
button.simulate('click');
button.simulate('click');

clock.tick(510);
expect(onClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
clock.uninstall();
```

PS for sure you could run `lolex.install()` and `clock.uninstall()` in `beforeEach`/`afterEach`

Answer (score 1):

You can return a promise and assert in it.

```
it('onScroll', () => {
    const component = shallow(<Component />);
    return new Promise(resolve=> {
       component.instance().onScroll();
       expect(mockOnScrollFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
       setTimeout(resolve,101);
   }
}
```