# How to test vue app that uses debounce from lodash

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, lodash

I have a Vue.js app and I'm using debounce from lodash to redirect to a new page:

```
const nav = debounce((vm) => {
  vm.$router.push({
    path: '/page',
  } )
}, 200)
```

When I run the jest test, this code is never executed.
I solve the problem surrounding the test code with

```
setTimeout(() => {
   //
}, 200)
```

Is there a better way to solve this problem ?
I've already tried to mock debounce but it doesn't work as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing debounced method in React with Enzyme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48787824/testing-debounced-method-in-react-with-enzyme)

Comment: have run into that too(ignore part about React, root cause is the same). if I have not missed any updates into lodash there is kind-of-tricky logic inside that needs mocking `Date()` constructor alongside `useFakeTimers`.

Comment: another alternative is to [mock `_.debounce`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3465#issuecomment-539496798) itself with your own and simpler implementation(but it would need more work to do)

Comment: I've created a mock but doesn't work

`export const debounce = jest.fn().mockImplementation((callback, timeout) => {
  console.log("devbounceee")
  let timeoutId = null;
  const debounced = jest.fn(() => {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = window.setTimeout(callback, timeout);
  });

  const cancel = jest.fn(() => {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  });

  debounced.cancel = cancel;
  return debounced;
});

export default debounce;`

Comment: with mock you still have to [`jest.useFakeTimers` + `jest.advanceTimersInTime`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks). Did you use them?

Comment: may you add test case's code?